# Get face lighting in "model world" without shaders. OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I have rather simple OpenGL workflow. I just use lists (no shaders attached to them):

```
glNewList(list, GL.COMPILE);
 //add vertices and normals
glEndList();
glCallList(list)
```

I want to get from OpenGL some information about faces of created object. Especially I need to know if their are on light or not for a given moment of time. Something like `glReadPixels` but not from framebuffer, but from 3D world.

**Is it possible via gl* functions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using any shaders, it is not possible to query any information on the geometry itself. OpenGL is not designed for geometry processing, it is a rendering API.

There are several ways to achieve what you need by using shaders:

- Perform the whole computation in a compute shader (probably the option with best performance).
- Use geometry shader and transform feedback.

How exactly you would implemented it depends on which data you have and on which computations should be performed.